# OracleException não é disparado!

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ado.net

Alguém já se deparou com o seguinte problema: Quando ocorre um erro que deveria ser do tipo tipo OracleException, mas em seu lugar é disparado um Exception, então o tratamento oracle não é aplicado por conta disto (os "..." são implementações suprimidas).

Veja exemplo:

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new     OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Oracle"].ConnectionString))
using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    try
    {
        //connection.Open(); //PARA PROVOCAR ERRO ORACLE
        (...)

        //Captura resultado em um DataReader
        //AO EXECUTAR ISTO NÃO LEVANTA ERRO ORACLE E SIM UM EXCEPTION SIMPLES.
        using (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader retornoBanco =     command.ExecuteReader()) 
        {
            (...)
        }
        (...)
    }
    catch (OracleException oe)
    {                           
          (...)
          switch (erroCodeOracle)
          {
              case 12571:
                  (...)
                  break;
              default:
                  (...)
                  break;
          }
    }

}
```

Não entra no CATCH acima! Mas o erro que retornar é "Conexão não está aberta..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editei a resposta porque a anterior tinha baixa qualidade.

Observando o binário a dentro encontrei (THE HORROR) alguns possíveis casos de exceção, um deles corrobora sua colocação de simples `Exception`:

```
if (this.m_isFromEF && this.m_connection.m_majorVersion < 12 && this.m_commandText.Contains(" APPLY "))
        {
          throw new Exception(OracleStringResourceManager.GetErrorMesg(ResourceStringConstants.ODP_NOT_SUPPORTED, "Oracle " + ((object) this.m_connection.ServerVersion).ToString(), "APPLY"));
        }
```

No mais em meus testes o erro é o mesmo da documentação Oracle: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll

Esse erro sempre vai ocorrer porque existe uma chamada a `ValidateStatePriorToExecution` na execução do comando:

```
private void ValidateStatePriorToExecution()
    {
      if (this.m_disposed)
        throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().Name);
      if (this.m_connection == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
      if (this.m_connection.m_connectionState != ConnectionState.Open)
        throw new InvalidOperationException(OracleStringResourceManager.GetErrorMesg(ResourceStringConstants.CON_CLOSED));
      if (this.m_commandImpl == null)
      {
        this.m_commandImpl = this.GetInitializedCommandImpl();
        if (this.m_commandImpl == null)
          throw new InvalidOperationException();
      }
      if (this.m_arrayBindCount > 1 && (this.m_parameters == null || this.m_parameters.Count == 0))
        this.m_commandImpl.m_arrayBindCount = 0;
      else
        this.m_commandImpl.m_arrayBindCount = this.m_arrayBindCount;
    }
```

Não consegui encontrar como poderia ser possível sair um OracleException desse código, visto que a documentação da Oracle também diz que a exceção é do tipo: `InvalidOperationException` e se você não der open o erro será pego no Validate acima.

Salvo o primeiro IF que se vier do EF com aquelas condições de versão e uso da palavra APPLY é apenas `Exception`.

Comment: Prezado, estou usando o cliente do Oracle (using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client). Obrigado mesmo assim...

Comment: Ok, investiguei e editei minha resposta.

Comment: Prezado, mais uma vez obrigado pelo seu empenho. Com sua resposta estou decidido a mudar minha estratégia e proteger o código de outra maneira, já que não poderei tratar este evento como o esperado. Já marquei sua análise como uma resposta válida. Mais uma vez obrigado!

Comment: Entendo sua frustração, eu mesmo que não uso Oracle fiquei frustrado com a documentação. Nem vou te falar da qualidade do código dentro do assembly porque não tenho nada de bom a falar. Na minha compreensão o OracleException é usado para erros de dentro do BD.